# Selecting appropriate ARM -mfpu option in gcc based on CPU features

Tags: c, gcc, arm, compiler-optimization

My CPU has following CPU features

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo 
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 1192.96

processor       : 1
BogoMIPS        : 1197.05

Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware        : sun7i
Revision        : 0000
```

And gcc sets

```
-march=armv7ve -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -meabi=5
```

options for

```
cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

compiled with

```
gcc -march=native -mtune=native -Q -v main.c
```

Isn't `neon-vfpv4`, which seems to be supported by CPU features, is superior to `vfpv3-d16`, which gcc sets?

I got only vague explanation of what `vfpv3-d16` is from [ARM's documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CIHCJIFE.html) and nothing on `neon-vfpv4`.

I'm using gcc 4.9.1

Comment: NEON is not ieee754 compliant, so gcc will probably not use it unless directed to with `-Ofast` (or unsafe-math-optimizations).

Comment: @EOF I'm compiling OpenCV on a Banana Pi ARM board, it will do some image processing, for which float point operation speed up could improve application's performance by a decent amount. What would you suggest using for `-mfpu`?

Comment: @EOF: that is relevant only for autovectorization. NEON is to vfp what SSE is to the x86 fpu.

Comment: @unixsmurf: That's not true. SSE/AVX are *more* ieee754 compliant than the **x87** fpu, unless you constantly write intermediate values to memory in x87. Basically, in x86 the old FPU is broken, in ARM the new FPU is broken.

Comment: @EOF: *sigh* no, NEON is not an "fpu replacement", it is a SIMD engine. No vectorization, no NEON, still vfp.

Comment: The fact that NEON FP instructions only utilise a subset of the VFP unit's precision, rounding modes and denormal behaviour doesn't make it "broken", any more than x86 floating-point libraries leaving the x87 in extended precision mode instead of setting it to IEEE754 double precision mode made that "broken".

Comment: @Notlikethat: Yes, x87 *is* broken. You *cannot* set it to do arithmetic in `float`/`double`-precision. *All* intermediate results and arithmetic are `long double`, only storing them to memory rounds. Yes, NEON *is* broken, at least for C, which specifies arithmetic to be done at `double` precision, while NEON (pre AARCH64) only works with `float`. Also, no full ieee754.

Comment: @EOF OK, I'll concede my x87 rustiness - I forgot the Precision Control field doesn't affect _all_ aspects. Back on topic, the significance of NEON in this question is that its presence, or lack of, governs how many VFP registers are available, which affects VFP code generation.To reiterate unixsmurf's point, NEON is _a SIMD engine_ - you can't use floating point in NEON unless (IEEE754-compliant) _VFP is also present_, thus complaining about NEON FP's lack of 754-compliance is akin to complaining about a Porsche 911's lack of luggage capacity - technically valid, but missing the point.

Comment: Also see the ARM Blog and [ARM Cortex-A Processors and GCC Command Lines](http://community.arm.com/groups/tools/blog/2013/04/15/arm-cortex-a-processors-and-gcc-command-lines).

Answer (score 6):

`-march` and `-mtune` (or `-mcpu` as a shorthand for both) only control the CPU options for instruction selection and scheduling. As an example, with a GCC 4.8-based cross-toolchain, when I do this:

```
 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -mcpu=arm250 -v -c test.c
```

I get this:

```
...
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mcpu=arm250' '-v' '-c' '-mfloat-abi=hard'
  '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' '-mthumb' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
...
```

which is clearly nonsense - the ARM250 predates VFP (and even Thumb) by a *long* way - because for any unspecified options it's just passing through whatever was configured as the default:

```
...
Configured with:
  ... --with-arch=armv7-a --with-tune=cortex-a9 --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 ...
    ... --with-mode=thumb --with-float=hard
```

Your Cortex-A7 indeed supports full VFPv4 and NEON, so passing `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4` to override the default would be the right thing to do. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an equivalent `-mfpu=native` option (at least documented - I don't have a native toolchain handy to check).

Comment: gcc's documentation says [`-mcpu=native causes the compiler to auto-detect the CPU of the build computer. At present, this feature is only supported on GNU/Linux, and not all architectures are recognized. If the auto-detect is unsuccessful the option has no effect.`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) I guess they just didn't bother much about improving it and parsing `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: As I said, `-mcpu` (cf. `-march`/`-mtune`) is independent of FPU options, and for good reason - _your_ Cortex-A7 has NEON and full VFPv4, but other Cortex-A7 implementations [may have only VFPv4-D16, or no FPU at all](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0464e/BABDAHCE.html), thus you need to specify the FPU type separately.